# What's the difference between ChannelFactory<T> and ClientBase<T>

Tags: wcf

can you explain to me please, What's the difference between ChannelFactory and ClientBase and which of them is better to use for a SelfHost Client-Server Apllication.

```
using(ChannelFactory<MyInterface> cf = new ChannelFactory<MyInterface>("Endpoint From Web.Config")){} 

public class MyClient : ClientBase<MyInterface>, MyInterface {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's have an interface that defines the contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface TheInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork( string Work );
}
```

The `ChannelFactory` automatically creates a proxy that only implements the interface.

```
 var factory = new ChannelFactory<TheInterface>( new BasicHttpBinding() );
 var address = new EndpointAddress( "http://..." );
 var client = factory.CreateChannel( address );

 // there are no other methods on the "client" reference
 // than the interface's DoWork method
 client.DoWork( "foo" );
```

On the other hand, a class that inherits from the `ClientBase` not only implements the interface but also exposes multiple additional properties that can be used to alter the behavior of the client.

```
public class TheInterfaceProxy : ClientBase<TheInterface>, TheInterface
{
    public TheInterfaceProxy( Binding binding, EndpointAddress address ) : base( binding, address ) { }

    public string DoWork( string Work )
    {
        return this.Channel.DoWork( Work );
    }
}
```

And then

```
var address = new EndpointAddress( "http://..." );

using ( var client = new TheInterfaceProxy( new BasicHttpBinding(), address ) )
{
     // DoWork is here
     // but multiple other members are there too
     // for example - applying a custom endpoint behavior:
     client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add( new InspectorBehavior() );

     client.DoWork( "bar" );
}
```

where an example simple behavior is used to inspect incoming/outgoing messages at the client side

```
class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    #region IEndpointBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters( ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters )
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior( ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime )
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add( new DispatchInspector() );
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior( ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher )
    {
    }

    public void Validate( ServiceEndpoint endpoint )
    {
    }

    #endregion
}

class DispatchInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    #region IClientMessageInspector Members

    public void AfterReceiveReply( ref Message reply, object correlationState )
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy( Int32.MaxValue );
        reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
        Console.WriteLine( "Receiving:\n{0}", buffer.CreateMessage().ToString() );
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest( ref Message request, IClientChannel channel )
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy( Int32.MaxValue );
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();
        Console.WriteLine( "Sending:\n{0}", buffer.CreateMessage().ToString() );

        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

There is no answer to *which is better*, however:

- if you don't need anything but the default behavior - you can stick with the `ChannelFactory`, it's the simplest of the two
- for anything extra, use the `ClientBase`, it requires an extra class, though

Comment: Hello Wiktor, thanks a lot for your reply. Inspect the InspectorBehavior and  the DispatchInspector calsses the behavoir of the TheInterfaceProxy class on the client side or what? When yes, how is the connection between these two classes with the TheInterfaceProxy class. Regards.

Comment: You seem to miss this line of code `client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add( new InspectorBehavior() );` that adds the inspector to behaviors of `TheInterfaceProxy`. This is something not possible with a proxy created with the channel factory.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I know now what is the difference between ChannelFactory and ClientBase programmatic. But what about other differences like asynchronous running, chaching, resource consumption, and speed? Are these two classes based on Rest or SOAP?

Comment: These additional questions go far beyond the scope of the original question, in my opinion. Consider accepting this as an answer and asking additional, specific questions that would address your concerns. Note that questions considered "too broad" will probably be put on hold by the community.

Comment: Hello Wiktor, sorry, but these were my real questions about the defference between the ChannelFactory<T> and ClientBase<T>. Regards.

Comment: Looks like you won't get any other answers then, considering the "real question" is asked in a comment below an answer that tries to address the question "as is".